# Как программно сменить внешний IP?

Tags: android

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Если вы отдаете себе отчет, что такое "внешный IP", то смотрите в сторону UPnP.

Comment: Этот ip выдается провайдером и, если он динамический, то что нужно сделать, чтобы его сменить ? Перезапустить интернет-соединение ?

Comment: А никто не гарантирует, что после переподключения, ip адрес сменится. Хотя я знаю способ, как наверняка перезапустить соединение - перезапустить телефон. :)

Comment: Строго говоря, сменить-то его можно, `ifconfig wlan0 1.2.3.4`. Только маршрутизировать дальше провайдер это не будет. :)

Comment: Ох, да, я прогнал насчет UPnP... Тут надо глубже копать

Comment: "а никто не гарантирует, что после переподключения, ip адрес сменится"
Ок, но все-таки как произвести переподключение?

Comment: Программно вы можете сменить только внутренний IP адрес. Внешний  вычисляется автоматически или выдается провайдером, если он статический ( платная услуга )

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы "произвести переподключение" - включить и выключить авиарежим, например.